# How to get bucket policy using Airflow s3 hook

Tags: amazon-s3, airflow, boto3

I would like to find out what is the bucket policy programmatically using Airflow S3 Hook, for a specific S3 bucket.
boto3 has [get_bucket_policy](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.get_bucket_policy) method, but [S3 hook](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-amazon/stable/_api/airflow/providers/amazon/aws/hooks/s3/index.html) doesn't seem to have it.
Is there any way to do that using the S3 hook?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get an instance of `boto3.S3.Bucket` calling `S3Hook.get_bucket` instance method.

This instance has a [Policy](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.9.42/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Bucket.Policy) method that can be used to access to policy resource associated to the bucket.

```py
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.hooks.s3 import S3Hook

s3_hook = S3Hook(aws_conn_id='aws_conn_id')
bucket = s3_hook.get_bucket('your-bucket-name')
policy_resource = bucket.Policy()

policy_json = policy_resource.policy
```